# Getting getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hostname error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, github, circleci

While doing semantic release I am getting this error.

An error occurred while running semantic-release: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hostname

**config.yml**

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.5
jobs:
  release:
    executor: node/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install-packages # Install and automatically cache packages
      # Run optional required steps before releasing
      # - run: npm run build-script
      - run:
          name: Install nvm
          command: |
            cd ..
            curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
            echo 'export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo '$GH_TOKEN'
      - run:
          name: Set node to version required by application for future circleci steps
          command: |
            cd ..
            nvm install 16.17.1
            NODE_VERSION=$(node -v)
            nvm alias default ${NODE_VERSION//v}             
      - run: npx semantic-release

workflows:
  test_and_release:
    # Run the test jobs first, then the release only when all the test jobs are successful
    jobs:
      - node/test:
          matrix:
            parameters:
              version:
                - 16.1.0
      - release:
          requires:
            - node/test
```

---

**release.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  branches: ['main', 'next'],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/npm",
    "@semantic-release/github",
    {
        "successComment": false
    },
    ["@semantic-release/git",
    {
      "assets": [
        {"path": ["lib/", "package.json"]},
      ],
      message: 'release: ${nextRelease.version} [skip Ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}',
    }],
  ]
}
```

---

**Error I am getting in circleci**

```
[3:18:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 19.0.5
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/github"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/git"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/git"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/github"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/github"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "success" from "@semantic-release/github"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "fail" from "@semantic-release/github"
[3:18:31 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Run automated release from branch main on repository https://github.com/name/project
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Allowed to push to the Git repository
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/npm"
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/npm] › ℹ  Verify authentication for registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/npm] › ℹ  Reading npm config from /home/circleci/project/.npmrc
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/npm] › ℹ  Wrote NPM_TOKEN to /tmp/dcd61cbf59ea4ff537d0750a83a9e9c5/.npmrc
name
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/npm"
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[3:18:32 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/github] › ℹ  Verify GitHub authentication (***************************************************************)
[3:18:39 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  Failed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[3:18:39 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/git"
[3:18:39 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/git"
[3:18:39 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: RequestError [HttpError]: request to ***************************************************************/repos/name/project failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hostname
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-node/index.js:110:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  status: 500,
  request: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '***************************************************************/repos/name/project',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
      'user-agent': 'octokit-rest.js/19.0.4 octokit-core.js/4.0.5 Node.js/16.17.1 (linux; x64)',
      authorization: 'token [REDACTED]'
    },
    request: { agent: undefined, hook: [Function: bound bound register] }
  },
  attemptNumber: 4,
  retriesLeft: 0,
  pluginName: '@semantic-release/github'
}
AggregateError: 
    HttpError: request to ***************************************************************/repos/name/project failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hostname
        at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-node/index.js:110:11
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:54:11
    at async Object.pluginsConf.<computed> [as verifyConditions] (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js:80:11)
    at async run (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:103:3)
    at async module.exports (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:269:22)
    at async module.exports (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

---

I am getting above error while doing release not sure what causing the issue.
semantic-release version is ^19.0.5.

Can anyone please help me on above issue ?